# Logging in with Identity Server 4 and nativescript-oauth2 Hangs

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-oauth2

I have an Nativescript app using the nativescriptoauth2 plugin to login.

After I authenticate on the identityserver page it hangs. If I close the webview and login again it is aleady autenticated and goes to a blank white page and sits there.

My config is

```
export function configureOAuthProviderIdentityServer(): TnsOaProvider {
    const identityServerProviderOptions: TnsOaProviderOptionsIdentityServer = {
        openIdSupport: 'oid-full',
        issuerUrl:
           'http://10.0.2.2:8000', // using localhost server
        clientId: 'mobile',
        urlScheme: 'com.company.go',
        redirectUri: 'com.company.go://auth',
        scopes: [ 'openid' ]
    };
```

This is the same issue now but It has no solution [Identity Server 4/nativescript Hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53980826/identity-server-4-nativescript-hangs)

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

I realised that the custom url scheme was not registered correctly. 
I had to reinstall the app in the emulator. 
After updating the AndroidManifest.xml and wiping the data of the emulator it worked.